# Regular Expression for url paths

Tags: regex, express

I want a regular expression to match on paths containing `'/food/'` but not `'/food/api/'`:

> http://example.com/food/api/pasta?sauce=true

Right now I'm using this:

```
/^((?!\/food\/api\/).)*$/
```

The problem with this is it matches ANY path that doesn't contain `'/food/api/'`

Behavior I want to achieve:

```
REGEX MATCHES
example.com/food/
example.com/food/meals

REGEX IGNORES
example.com/food/api/pasta?sauce=true
example.com/food/api/pasta
example.com/food/api/
example.com/meal
example.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pattern like this `((?!\/food\/api\/).)*` (a tempered greedy token solution) will match the whole line if it does not contain the sub string `/food/api`

As the quantifier is a `*` it will also match an empty line.

Instead, you can use an alternation to match until the first occurrence of a `/` followed by food or meal followed and a forward slash. After this slash, check that it is not followed by `/api`

```
^[^/]+/(?:food|meal)/(?!api/).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/793AHR/1)

If the string can not contains spaces, you can exclude them using the negated character class `[^/\s]+` and match `\S*` instead of `.*`

```
^[^/\s]+/(?:food|meal)/(?!api/)\S*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKISaU/1)

Comment: What syntax would be needed to shorten this up so it does a 'contains' check instead of starts the string at 'http/s'?

Comment: @OP I have added an update. You can leave out the protocol in that case.